# Guldinus theorem

Tags: analysis, surface-integrals, centroid

Can I use [Guldinus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) to calculate the z co-ordinate of the center of mass of a homogeneous solid,

for example, if I have 
$D = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 1 ≤ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ 9, z ≥ 0 \}$,

how can I proceed to calculate the z coordinate of the centre of mass ?
I have used this formula

$Za = \int \frac{zdxdydz}{V(a)}$

and I went to polar co-ordinates , can someone help me to do all the calculation so I see if I understood the concept ?

Comment: Did you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) theorem?

Comment: yes i do can you solve it please

Comment: I don't think you can calculate the centre of mass of the solid from the theorem itself. I don't think you understand the theorem as it is the centroid of the figure you rotate that relates to the theorem.